How to avoid or bypass the weekly re-input credential for Interactive Broker Gateway(IBGW) to keep connected?
would like to connect to Interactive Broker through IBGW for non-high-frequency trading.
Per the official document, TWS API V9.72 Document, I have to re-enter the credential manually every week. How do we avoid or bypass that?
Prefer to keep connected monthly or yearly, similar to what I do with the Tiger Broker API.
Thanks


You have no agency to change the API provider's policy. Write a script to reauthenticate you at a sufficient frequency so that your account doesn't  lose access.

Any existing repo? E.g. in github?

It depends on your authentication method and it is extremely difficult to automate. Some people still have the key card, others have the mobile app, then some have the key generator device. The key card is probably the simplest but requires you to enter all the codes and then some code to read the requested numbers. With the key generator device it's impossible.

As suggested in the comments, the only way to maintain the connection for a prolonged period of time is via re-authentication scripts. You could check out these repos depending on your needs.

Authentication and maintenance tool used for the Interactive Brokers Client Portal Web API Gateway: https://github.com/Voyz/ibeam
REST and WebSocket client library for Interactive Brokers Client Portal Web API: https://github.com/Voyz/ibind
IBC automates many aspects of running Interactive Brokers Trader Workstation and Gateway, including filling in the login and password: https://github.com/IbcAlpha/IBC
A docker image to run the Interactive Brokers Gateway Application without any human interaction on a docker container: https://github.com/UnusualAlpha/ib-gateway-docker

This is for the web client API, which is completely separate from the "full" API for TWS and Gateway.

Added a couple more links. IBC is the right one for TWS and Gateway. 2FA still needs to be handled manually.

It doesn't address the OP's issue though.
